# Query from 2 tables questions

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have two tables:

Table R5EVENTS:

```
EVT_CODE     EVT_JOBTYPE       EVT_UDFCHAR05
   1             A                1111
   2             B                2222
   3             A                3333
   4             C                4444
```

Table R5BOOKEDHOURS:

```
BOO_EVENT     BOO_HOURS     BOO_PERSON
   1             2            ADG
   1             5            POL 
   1             1            TAD
   2             3            POL
   2             4            TAD
   3             2            ADG
   3             5            POL
   4             1            TAD
   4             2            POL
   4             3            ADG
```

When I run this query:

```
select 
    EVT_JOBTYPE, COUNT (EVT_CODE), SUM(BOO_HOURS)
from 
    R5BOOKEDHOURS 
inner join 
    R5EVENTS on EVT_CODE = BOO_EVENT 
where 
    BOO_PERSON is not null
group by 
    EVT_JOBTYPE
```

I get this:

```
EVT_JOBTYPE     COUNT(EVT_CODE)     SUM(BOO_HOURS)
    A                  5                  15
    B                  2                  7
    C                  3                  6
```

What I need is that COUNT(EVT_CODE) only counts codes on R5EVENTS, where the work orders are created, not from R5BOOKEDHOURS, because there the EVT_CODE/BOO_EVENTS is repeated each time a worked registers an hour.

I would like to get:

```
EVT_JOBTYPE     COUNT(EVT_CODE)     SUM(BOO_HOURS)
    A                  2                 15
    B                  1                 7
    C                  1                 6
```

UPDATE (tables above too):

I have another table R5ORDERLINES with prices (R5ORDERLINES.ORL_ORDER = R5EVENTS.EVT_UDFCHAR05)

```
ORL_PART     ORL_ORDQTY     ORL_PRICE     ORL_ORDER
   AA           5             100           1111 
   BB           2             500           2222
   CC           1             200           3333
   DD           10            2000          4444
```

I need to get the SUM of all ORL_PRICES that correspond to one EVT_ORDER, grouped at the same time by EVT_JOBTYPE as we did in the first query.

Result:

```
EVT_JOBTYPE     COUNT(EVT_CODE)     SUM(BOO_HOURS)    ORL_PRICE
    A                  2                 15             300
    B                  1                 7              500
    C                  1                 6              2000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
select EVT_JOBTYPE,
count(EVT_CODE),
sum(SumBOO_HOURS)
from
(
    select EVT_JOBTYPE,
    EVT_CODE,
    SUM(BOO_HOURS) as SumBOO_HOURS
    from R5BOOKEDHOURS inner join R5EVENTS on EVT_CODE = BOO_EVENT 
    where bh.BOO_PERSON is not null
    group by EVT_JOBTYPE,
    EVT_CODE
) PreGroupedData
group by EVT_JOBTYPE
```

Comment: This Works fine, thanks :D But I need to complicate is a little but more... updating first post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two different data groups to join, to achieve this. One simple way is this:

```
select e.EVT_JOBTYPE, MAX(EVT_CODE_COUNT) AS EVT_CODE_COUNT, SUM(BOO_HOURS)
from R5BOOKEDHOURS bh
inner join R5EVENTS e on e.EVT_CODE = bh.BOO_EVENT 
inner join (SELECT EVT_JOBTYPE, COUNT(*) AS EVT_CODE_COUNT FROM R5EVENTS GROUP BY EVT_JOBTYPE) temp on temp.EVT_JOBTYPE = e.EVT_JOBTYPE
where bh.BOO_PERSON is not null
group by e.EVT_JOBTYPE
```

A better optimized way would be to create a #temp table first and then hit a join it.